# How to import CSS modules with Typescript, React and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, css-modules

How to import CSS modules in Typescript with Webpack?

1. Generate (or auto-generate) `.d.ts` files for CSS? And use classic Typescript `import` statement? With `./styles.css.d.ts`:

   ```
   import * as styles from './styles.css'
   ```
2. Import using `require` Webpack function?

   ```
   let styles = require("./styles.css");
   ```

But for the last approach I must define the `require` function.

What is the best approach or best option and one that can also handle IntelliSense for the CSS file definitions and classes?

Answer (score 105):

Now in the year 2021, all you need to do is add a `src/Globals.d.ts` to your project with these lines:

```
declare module "*.module.css";
declare module "*.module.scss";
// and so on for whatever flavor of css you're using
```

Then install and add

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  }
}
```

to your tsconfig.

Example of this correctly functioning in VS code after making that simple change (root is a class defined in my stylesheet):

[image]

Webpack and tsc also compile correctly on the command line.

Comment: In second to this if you may also checkout on this blog https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/06/22/css-module-typescript/#comment-680455

Comment: There is one Important step **missing**: \ 
**`ensure that VS Code will use the project’s version of Typescript instead of the VS Code version`** https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/06/22/css-module-typescript/ \ 
-- \
If adding the **setting.json** file at the Vscode Folder Level Setting doesnt work, try use Workspace Level setting. \
Or, change the setting in **`TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version...`** in Vscode \
Or, for instruction with **graphs**, see https://puruvj.dev/blog/css-modules-typescript-intellisense#Set-VSCode-TypeScript-version

Answer (score 60):

A) As you are saying, there is one simplest (not best) option to use **require**:

```
const css = require('./component.css')
```

- We need to have typings for `require` as it's not standard feature in typescript.
- Simplest typing for this specific require may be:

  ```
  declare function require(name: string): string;
  ```
- Webpack will then compile typescript and use modules properly - **BUT without any IDE help and class names checks for build**.

B) There is better solution to use standard **import**:

```
import * as css from './component.css'
```

- enables full **class names IntelliSense**
- requires types definition for each css file, otherwise `tsc` compiler will fail

For proper IntelliSense, Webpack needs to generate types definition for each css file:

1. Use webpack [typings-for-css-modules-loader](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader)

   ```
   webpackConfig.module.loaders: [
     { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'typings-for-css-modules?modules' }
     { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'typings-for-css-modules?modules&sass' }
   ];
   ```
2. Loader will generate `*.css.d.ts` files for each of css files in your codebase
3. Typescript compiler will understand that css import will be module with properties (class names) of type string.

Mentioned `typings-for-css-loader` contains [a bug](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader/issues/33) and because of types file generation delay, it's best to declare global `*.css` type in case our `*.css.d.ts` file is not generated yet.

That [little bug](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader/issues/33) scenario:

1. Create css file `component.css`
2. Include it in component `import * as css from './component.css'`
3. Run `webpack`
4. Typescript compiler will try to compile code (ERROR)
5. Loader will generate Css modules typings file (`component.css.d.ts`), but it's late for typescript compiler to find new typings file
6. Run `webpack` again will fix build error.

Easy fix is to create global definition (eg. file called `typings.d.ts` in your source root) for importing CSS Modules:

```
declare module '*.css' {
  interface IClassNames {
    [className: string]: string
  }
  const classNames: IClassNames;
  export = classNames;
}
```

This definition will be used if there is no css file generated (eg. you have added new css file). Otherwise will be used generated specific *(needs to be in same folder and named same as source file + `.d.ts` extension)*, eg. `component.css.d.ts` definition and IntelliSense will work perfectly.

Example of `component.css.d.ts`:

```
export const wrapper: string;
export const button: string;
export const link: string;
```

*And if you don't want to see generated css typings you may setup filter in IDE to hide all files with extension .css.d.ts in your sources.*

Answer (score 37):

I have added a file named `Global.d.ts` or `typings.d.ts` to my `./src` folder with some type definitions:

```
declare module "*.module.css";
```

Webpack css config:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    isProductionBuild ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
        sourceMap: true,
        minimize: true
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Then I simply import the module like: `import styles from "./App.module.css";`

Comment: Just to add to this - if you're using create-react-app with the --typescript flag, their webpack configuration expects CSS modules to be named `*.module.css`. So all you need to do to make the "import a from b" syntax work is rename all .css files to File.module.css and import them like `import styles from "./File.module.css"`.

Answer (score 24):

In 2022, all I needed to do it to add `Globals.d.ts` file under the `src` folder
with

```
declare module "*.module.css";
declare module "*.module.scss";
```

Then I can import CSS modules in my typescript files as usual for css or scss files:

```
import styles from "./Team.module.scss";
```

Comment: Error: not found module

Answer (score 4):

I use `create-react-app`, but for some reason other solutions didn't work, something was missing; I think it's because `VS Code` uses its own `TypeScript` vesrion. So here is all I did until it finally worked; if you use `create-react-app` & `VS Code` it should work for you as well:

1. run `npm i typescript-plugin-css-modules --save-dev`
2. in the project's root folder, create a file named `styles.d.ts` (or
   something like this) and paste the following content:

***styles.d.ts***

```
// if you use css
declare module "*.module.css" {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

// if you use scss
declare module "*.module.scss" {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

// if you use less
declare module "*.module.less" {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

3. in .vscode/settings.json (create the file if you don't already have it) - add the below fields:

***.vscode/settings.json***

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
"typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true
```

So, the file might look like so:

***.vscode/settings.json***

```
{
   "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
   "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true
}
```

Comment: For some reason I only needed to install the plugin, add it in `tsconfig.json`. Didn't need to create a `.d.ts` file or set `typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk`.
**Setting `typescript.tsdk` in VS Code Settings was what finally got it working for me!**

Answer (score 3):

> Or import using require webpack function

This is just what I *used* to do and still have that code in a few of my projects out there.

---

Now : I wrote typestyle : http://typestyle.github.io/#/ but you don't have to use it. Just stick with `const styles = require('./styles.css')` if it makes you happy. FWIW you can also use raw css with typestyle if you want http://typestyle.github.io/#/raw

Answer (score 2):

I think now typescript can import css file by simply doing
import 'fileTobeImportedPath.css'

Answer (score 2):

This case is related to Typescript. You can add `typings.d.ts` in your project with this content:

```js
declare module "*.module.css";
declare module "*.module.scss";
```

It is good practice to use file name with `*.module.*` format if you want to enable CSS Module.

[`css-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) will enable CSS Module automatically for files with name that satisfy this RegEx: `/\.module\.\w+$/i`. This feature is customable by setting `options.modules` property as an object.

For example:

```js
import style from './App.module.css'; // CSS Module enabled
import './index.css'; // Plain CSS loaded
```

For recent configuration, you can add this rule to `webpack.config.js`:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        modules: {
          localIdentName: "[hash:base64]", // default
          auto: true // default
        },
        sourceMap: true
      }
    },
  ]
},
```

A custom configuration example:

```js
{
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
    modules: {
      localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]", // custom class name format
      auto: /\.cmod\.\w+$/i, // custom auto enable CSS Module for "*.cmod.css" format
    },
  }
},
```

Complete documentation is [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader#object).

Comment: Is it good practice to use .module.css or is it required? Because if it's not required then it's not good practice to make people use that rediculous naming convention.

Comment: It's already commonly used by popular libraries such as CSS Loader or Angular to detect files that apply CSS modules. So, it is good practice to align with communities. The name is also acceptable and easily differentiated.

Answer (score 2):

### This is the easiest way in 2024:

1. Create the file `globals.d.ts` file under the `src`
2. Put this code there

```
declare module '*.scss'
```

3. Now you can import like this

```
import styles from './App.module.scss'
```

4. Then install and add in your `package.json`

```
npm i mini-css-extract-plugin
```

5. Then add in `webpack.config.ts`

```
   {
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
      use: [
        devMode 
        ? "style-loader" 
        : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        "css-loader",
        options: {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  modules: true,
        },
        "sass-loader",
      ],
    }
```

Answer (score -12):

`let styles = require("./styles.css");` is the best approch because it is es5 version of javascript which is compatible with every feature of react.`import * as styles from './styles.css'` is es6 version of javascript.

Comment: its neither es5 nor es6, it is typescript and as such will be transpiled.

Comment: I agree with @Meirion Hughes.  thanks to all  for the responses !