# TS2307: Cannot find module './tables.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

So I'm using css modules in create-react-app project, and for some reason I have this error:
[image]

in Google Chrome browser:

[image]
yet, it seems to be like eslint error, because in browser I can close warning modal and all my styles are applied and app is working as intended.

Tables.tsx

```
import styles from "./Tables.module.css";

export const Tables = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>Tables</div>
  )
}
```

Tables.module.css

```
.card {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

folder structure:

[image]

What I am missing here? Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your project folder structure? That way the link for the import can be checked too.

Comment: In unedited version I managed to name my components with lowerCase letter. Thought that might be a problem. Yet after changes still error in terminal. Might be problem with some of the config files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe typescript is not recognizing the CSS file as a *module*, so it's throwing you an error on not finding one by that name.

Answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336858/how-to-import-css-modules-with-typescript-react-and-webpack) may be helpful as a reference. In case that doesn't help, I think there may be an issue with the path resolution for the module, so [here's how typescript resolves modules/paths](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md#how-typescript-resolves-modules).