# Can't import tailwind css file in a Remix.js project without TS throwing an error

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, remix

[image]

I have tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356082/5872611) but it still doesn't work

Here are my configs:

`remix.config.ts`:

```
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  postcss: true,
  tailwind: true,
}
```

`tailwind.config.ts`

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

export default {
  content: ['./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
} satisfies Config
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Remix version 2.3 and my `tsconfig.json` filelooks like this

```json
{
  "include": ["remix.env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

`Module` and `ModuleResolution` are the items you need to make sure you have.